# Can I replace a pattern fill with solid fill on SVG files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a SVG file with a shape that has a pattern fill. Can I replace the pattern fill with just a solid fill color in Illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine all you need to do is select it, then grab a color from a color pallet and it will change. It should be that easy